# Google Adwords and Facebook Ads attribution

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, attribution

I'm trying to work out a solution to work out a better attribution model for each user registration on my website.

When an user completes a registration they are taken to /register/complete/[user_id]

My current solution is to pull all visits to /register/complete with the RGoogleAnalytics package querying for page path and campaign without any sampling.

However, it doesn't account for example users that might have been shown/clicked on a facebook ad a few days before and either googled or visited the site directly to register.

I'm searching for a solution which can attribute each registration to the mix of facebook and google adwords campaigns

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin attributing your Adwords traffic by linking your GA account to your Adwords account. Instructions for this can be found here: [GA setup](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6209127?hl=en)

To attribute Facebook ads to your registrations, you can implement a Facebook pixel on your site. Facebook pixel instructions can be found here: [FB Pixels](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755)

I would also recommend setting up google tag manager on your site, that way you only need to add one script on your site.